# Mongo Replicaset configuration from JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

Is it possible to configure Mongo Replica-sets from JAVA application?

Are there JAVA APIs for rs.initiate(), rs.add(), etc?

I am looking to configure mongo replica-sets from applications without the need to log into mongo console manually.

Are there ways to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way, you can only accomplish this via database `admin` and `runCommand`.

Here is the pseudo example for `rs.add`:

```
val client = new MongoClient(ip, port);
val db = client.getDatabase("admin");
val conf = db.runCommand({ replSetGetConfig: 1}).get("config", Document.class);
val members = conf.get("members", List.class);

members.add({ "_id": 10, "host": "192.168.1.110:27001" });

// we need to update the config version to make config acceptible
conf.put("version", conf.getInteger("version" + 1));
conf.put("members", members);

db.runCommand({ replSetReconfig: conf });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB.eval()` function.

Comment: This answer appeared in Low Quality Posts review queue. Could you please elaborate a little bit more @MikeShauneu so the Original Poster would know why he should use `DB.eval()`? I strongly recommend reading [answer]. [- From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14306874)